# How to clear unneeded Oracle 11g backup files that can't be applied?

Tags: oracle-11g

I have inherited an Oracle 11g DB running on Windows. The first order of business is taking care of an HD space issue which is caused by over 2000 archive file (.001 files).  As I understand it, these are made by Oracle and are managed using a utility called RMAN.

Using RMAN, I have discovered none of these files have been "applied" to the DB and they can't be because a bunch of them are missing.  I'm not sure what to do now.  The DB is healthy atm but if there is a problem, recovery is not an option as things stand.

Now if I had a problem like this in MSSQL I could flip the recovery mode to SIMPLE and then back to FULL and it would clear all the old transaction log files and restart everything.  Is there a way to do something with Oracle that would give me the same effect?

Comment: You should be able to use RMAN to take a new backup (and establish a new baseline), then delete obsolete archivelogs.